# It is countable

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm looking for three words. Try to find them.

---

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The words are created by

> Recreating the shapes in the left grid with the numbers being the vertices in a clockwise manner, and then mapping onto the grid on the right

So the three words are:

> **VERTICES OF POLYGONS** - what we use to find the answer!!

Images:

> [image]
>  [image]
>
> Triangle: **VER**
> Square: **TICE**
> Pentagon: **SOFPO**
> Hexagon: **LYGONS**
>
> = **VERTICES OF POLYGONS**! (Which, from the title, are also countable!)

Comment: All good. Well done!